# How to display an entry id multiple times?

Tags: entries

I've set up a print template for furniture labels.
I let my client print the labels with a special Link like

```
/label?ids="x|y|z"
```

It all works good. Now he sometimes wants to print the same label multiple times, so he and I tried the following:

```
/label?ids="x|x|x|y|z|z|z"
```

The underlying code is the following:

```
{% set ids = craft.request.param('ids')| split('|')|join(',') %}
{% set params =
    {
        section: 'furniture',
        limit : null,
        id: ids

    }
%}
{% paginate craft.entries(params) as entries %}
{% for entry in entries %}
     ...
{% endfor %}
```

This will only display x and z one time.

Is there a way around this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write something like this:

```
{% set ids = craft.request.param('ids')| split('|') %}
{% for id in ids %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.id(id).first() %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, to reduce the queries, store all the entries in a variable and then loop through ids and find the right match in this smaller set.

Comment: Don't you need to add `.first` to `craft.entries` since it returns an object?

Comment: Yes, right, edited.

Comment: You need a dot before `first()`!

Comment: Hi, this worked like a charm. And yes, please add the the dot before `first()`. Thanks a lot!